# Find sum of factors of given integer and divide it by the given integer

Tags: c, loops, if-statement, factors

I'm new to C language and I could really use help with this question:

**The abundancy of an integer is defined as the perfect divisors of a number (factors not including the number itself) divided by the number itself.  For example, the abundance of 8 is (1+2+4)/8 = 7/8.  Write a C function which takes a single integer as input and returns the abundance of that number.**

This is as far as I got. I can compile it but I keep getting the incorrect answer. Please help and thanks in advance

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int number, i, sum, abundancy;
    sum==0;
    abundancy==0;

    printf("Enter an integer:");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    for(i=1; i<=number; i++)
    {
        if (i!=number)
        {
            if (number%i == 0)
            {
                sum+=i;
                    {
                        abundancy=sum/number;
                        printf("The abundancy is %d", abundancy);
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- This is as far as I got on an online compiler
  [image]
- This is what I get when I compile it
  [image]

Comment: `sum==0;
 abundancy==0;` does not assign 0. Read about `==` operator and for assignment  you should use `=`.

Comment: And `abundancy=sum/number;` results in `int` hence `7/8` is `0`.

Comment: Thanks! I've changed the sum==0 and abundancy==0 to sum=0 and abundancy =0 like you said. But for the second part I'm not really sure how to correct it though, I get what you mean I'm just still really really new to this so I don't know how to correct it.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing `abundancy=sum/number;` inside the loop which is going to fetch you wrong results. Here is the correct version of your code with the changes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int number, i, sum, abundancy;
    sum=0;                       //USE ASSIGNMENT NOT EQUAL TO OPERATOR
    abundancy=0;                 //USE ASSIGNMENT NOT EQUAL TO OPERATOR

    printf("Enter an integer:");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    for(i=1; i<number; i++)                 //CHANGED
    {
        if (number%i == 0)              //ONLY SINGLE IF NEEDED
        {
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    abundancy = sum/number;
    printf("Abundancy is: %d/%d\n",sum,number);   //ADDED 
    printf("abundancy is: %d\n",abundancy);

    return 0;
}
```

Even then `abundancy` will contain floor value of `sum/number` - you should use `float` instead and `%f` as format specifier while printing.

**INPUT:**

```
12
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 abundancy is: 16/12
 abundancy is: 1
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much! It works omg. But why don't I need the if(i!=number) though?

Comment: @Christine Because the problem statement says `factors not including the number itself` - for that I have already amended the `for` loop by using `<number` rather that `<=number`.

Comment: Sorry I just realized you changed the condition in the for loop so you wouldn't have to do the if(i!=number). Thanks again:)

Comment: @Christine Since it helped, you might wan to visit this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :) Welcome to SO

Comment: [What should You do when someone answers Your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)